# Where is the 'pacman' style loading icon?

Tags: jhipster

I would like to replace this animation (i.e. the animated pacman image displayed on initial page load).. but where should I be looking ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "pacman" loading icon is configured in [src/main/webapp/content/css/loading.css](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/f76f94962b34c767b056bc915de9827132130214/src/main/webapp/content/css/loading.css)

The HTML that `loading.css` applies to is in [src/main/webapp/index.html](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/f76f94962b34c767b056bc915de9827132130214/src/main/webapp/index.html#L21-L28)